# Getting BUILD SUCCESSFUL but non of the test cases are getting executing in android studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am not getting where i am going wrong. Using android studio and trying to write test cases. I created a new project and the structure is :

```
-app
 -src
  -androidTests
   -java (com.example.testdemo.tests)
       - MainActivityTest 
  -main
   -java (com.example.testdemo)
       -MainActivity
   -res
   -AndroidManifest
```

I will go step by step :
1. *build.gradle* file content

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testdemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "com.example.testdemo.tests"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

2. *MainActivityTest.java*

   ```
   import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
   import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import com.example.webonise.testdemo.MainActivity;
   import com.example.webonise.testdemo.R;

   public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {


   private TextView tv;
   private MainActivity mActivity;

   public MainActivityTest(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
       super(activityClass);
   }

   @Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();
       mActivity = getActivity();
       tv = (TextView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv);
       assertNotNull("Text view is null",tv);
   }

   public void testPreconditions(){
       assertNotNull("Text view is null",tv);
   }

   @SmallTest
   public void checkTextViewText(){
       String text = tv.getText().toString();
       assertEquals(mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world), text);
   }

   @SmallTest
   public void checkTextViewText2(){
       String text = tv.getText().toString();
       assertEquals("fail", text);
   }
   }
   ```
3. In studio Terminal i am giving this command:  ***./gradlew connectedCheck***

   I am getting BUILD SUCCESSFUL but the report generated is showing this :

   ---

Test Summary
0
tests
0

### failures

### duration

successful
Classes
Class   Tests   Failures    Duration    Success rate

---

I appreciate you help.

Comment: Have you tried to name your test folder from `androidTest` to `test`?

Comment: And its works .... you are awesome ... changed "androidTests" to "tests" and DONE. You can post this answer i will accept it.

Comment: Changed "androidTests" to "tests" and it works. Now its showing one test case executed "ExampleUnitTest". Still non of my test cases are executed. Can you help?

Comment: I can look at it in about two hours - maybe recheck which annotations are necessary in your test class.

Comment: Do you have any device connected (and recognized)? Either a virtual or a real one?

Comment: I have nexus connected.

Comment: Sorry, my experience with Android is quite limited, I just read that `src/androidTest/java` is the default test directory for Android (but it seems that it's just `androidTest`, no plural)

I can chat with you privately in about two hours if you want to, now I'm afk for a while :)

Comment: yes i know ... but for some reason .. my build fails if i give "androidTest" as parent. It works with "andriodTests" ,"test" and even with "tests".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90518/discussion-between-ranvijay-and-stuxnet).